# Javascript keyword color in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

It is possible to change color of keyword JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012?
In my aspx page I have some JS code, I would like see code more comfortable.

In VS2010 it was possilbe (Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Fonts and Colors -> Script keyword), but in VS 2012 this position dissapear from dropdownlist :/

Answer (score 4):

It is still at the same place: Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Fonts and Colors

[image]

Comment: In VS2010 this option (from dropdownlist) was named "Script keyword" in VS 2012 it dissappear! Which "Display Item" should I choose to set color of JS keyword.

Comment: "Keyword" is the display item you need to change

Answer (score 3):

Search for 'Identifier', 'Keyword' and 'String' to adjust the colors for JS